# APIM Policy - AAD ClientID Restriction

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have multiple APIs which are hosted in APIM and are accessed by both User Principal and Service Principal (App Authentication) via Azure AD token. I have below requirement to achieve it through APIM policy:

1. If Authentication mode is UPN, all API should be accessed.
2. If Authentication mode is SPN, I want to give access to only selected ClientIds and only specific APIs

Is this achievable by APIM and how will performance be impacted by this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using choose policy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-advanced-policies#choose) to inspect token you have (see .AsJwt method here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-policy-expressions) and conditionally apply one or another validate-jwt policy (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-access-restriction-policies#ValidateJWT).